# Interpolation Simulation (String Formatting)

Tags: java, format

here's an example:

```
int n1 = 20;
int n2 = 40;
String output = String.format("Some guy is **%d** years old while the other is **%d** ", n1, n2);
System.out.println(output);
```

Why does this not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find  it works well when i'm testing, and it will print as belows:

```
  Some guy is 20 years old while the other is 40
```